# Outgoing payments with Paypal ipn and pdt

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is it possible to get outgoing payments and any outgoing transactions via ipn service?
I enabled ipn and i am receiving only ingoing payments from customers.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no IPN for outgoing payments, but PayPal will send an email notification for outgoing payments. IPN for only incoming payments. For outgoing payments, you will need to rely on PayPal account reports and email notifications.